# Apply css style to child element

Tags: html, css

Here is an sample example

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .test > input {     //this is wrong.
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="test">
        <div>
            <input></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is apply a style to input element. How to select a input element. with the help of div's css style name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can just use `.test input` (which will apply to every input in `<div class="test">`).

Your CSS with `>` only selects direct descendants

Answer (score 4):

```
div.test input{

}
```

will style all inputs nested in the div of class test

```
div.test input:first-child{

}
```

will style only the first nested input.

the ">" operator only styles directly descendent elements, so it will not style your inputs because you have div.test > div > input, the div in between div.test and input makes it so the input is not directly descendent to div.test

Comment: Not adjacent - direct descendant

Answer (score 4):

If you want to apply style to input using div with class="test", you can do like this

```
<style>
    .test > div > input {
        color:red;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

As none of the other answers have mentioned this before, for this particular case you could also use the `*` selector. It matches descendants that are grandchildren or later descendants. You would use it like so: `.test * input`.